# Why android is set at most 4 background Process?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

I know android run on Single thread but I want to execute more than 4 process.Any idea about why android set at most 4 process.

Comment: Are you talking threads or processes? Where did the number 4 come from?

Comment: No I am talking about background process like service.

Comment: What does NDK have to do with this? More context, please.

Answer (score 0):

If you want any component to run into another process [`android:process`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#proc) might help.

**From Docs:**

> By setting this attribute to a process name that's shared with another
>   application, you can arrange for components of both applications to
>   run in the same process — but only if the two applications also share
>   a user ID and be signed with the same certificate.